# MSVC compiler generates ineffective code for unrolled loop with pointer comparison

Tags: c, pointers, optimization, visual-c++, x86

MSVC compiler generates ineffective code if we have the loop with more than 2 unrolled iterations and pointer comparison.

MSVC compiler inserts one unnecessary instruction in loop to work with pointer comparison.
It changes pointer before loop, and then it inserts unnecessary LEA instruction in loop to restore pointer value for pointer comparison.

```
msvc compiler for x86 (32-bit):
-O2 -arch:IA32

void proc(unsigned *a, unsigned *stop)
{
  do {
    a[0]++;
    a[1]++;
    a[2]++;
    a[3]++;
    a += 4;
  }
  while (a != stop);
}

void proc(unsigned int *,unsigned int *) PROC                             ; proc, COMDAT
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _a$[esp-4]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR _stop$[esp-4]
        add     eax, 8
        npad    5
$LL4@proc:
        inc     DWORD PTR [eax-8]
        lea     eax, DWORD PTR [eax+16]
        inc     DWORD PTR [eax-20]
        lea     ecx, DWORD PTR [eax-8]
        inc     DWORD PTR [eax-16]
        inc     DWORD PTR [eax-12]
        cmp     ecx, edx
        jne     SHORT $LL4@proc
        ret     0
```

There is same behavior for any other loops including AVX or SSE loops, if there are more than 2 unrolled iterations and pointer comparison for loop exit.

Is there any reason for that weired behavior of compiler?
And is there any way to fix it?

The code with counter can be more effective with MSVC than code with pointer comparison.
But another compilers can generate optimal code for such loops with
pointer comparison.

Only if there are 1 or 2 unrolled iterations, then the generated code is optimal:

```
void proc(unsigned *a, unsigned *stop)
{
  do {
    a[0]++;
    a[1]++;
    a += 2;
  }
  while (a != stop);
}
_a$ = 8                                       ; size = 4
_stop$ = 12                                   ; size = 4
_proc   PROC                                      ; COMDAT
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _stop$[esp-4]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _a$[esp-4]
$LL4@proc:
        inc     DWORD PTR [eax]
        inc     DWORD PTR [eax+4]
        add     eax, 8
        cmp     eax, ecx
        jne     SHORT $LL4@proc
        ret     0
_proc   ENDP
```

Another example with more pressure for ALU resource:

https://godbolt.org/z/ccGvTsWM9

```
unsigned Sum(unsigned *a, unsigned *stop)
{
  unsigned sum = 0;    
  do {
    sum += a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3];
    a += 4;
  }
  while (a != stop);
  return sum;
}

        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _a$[esp-4]
        xor     eax, eax
        push    esi
        mov     esi, DWORD PTR _stop$[esp]
        add     ecx, 8
        npad    2
$LL4@Sum:
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [ecx-8]
        lea     ecx, DWORD PTR [ecx+16]
        add     edx, DWORD PTR [ecx-20]
        add     edx, DWORD PTR [ecx-12]
        add     edx, DWORD PTR [ecx-16]
        add     eax, edx
        lea     edx, DWORD PTR [ecx-8]
        cmp     edx, esi
        jne     SHORT $LL4@Sum
        pop     esi
        ret     0
```

UPDATE:
Workaround for that problem is to update pointer several times per one loop iteration. In that case MSVS creates smaller code without two `LEA` instructions. The speed looks the same in my tests. Probably best pointer step is `2`, because msvc for arm64 uses `ldp` / `stp` instructions in another loops if `pointer_step==2`, and it doesn't use `ldp` / `stp` if `pointer_step==1`.

```
void proc(unsigned *a, unsigned *stop)
{
  do {
    a[0]++;
    a[1]++;
    a += 2;
    a[0]++;
    a[1]++;
    a += 2;
  }
  while (a != stop);
}

; proc, COMDAT
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _stop$[esp-4]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _a$[esp-4]
$LL4@proc:
        inc     DWORD PTR [eax]
        inc     DWORD PTR [eax+4]
        inc     DWORD PTR [eax+8]
        inc     DWORD PTR [eax+12]
        add     eax, 16                             ; 00000010H
        cmp     eax, ecx
        jne     SHORT $LL4@proc
        ret     0
```

Comment: Cant reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/31aa6Mxj5

Comment: @0___________ you chose the wrong compiler: Try this: https://godbolt.org/z/MG8e6c9Yb

Comment: @Jabberwocky he did not state which one. He also stated avx

Comment: Which "unnecessary instruction" are you refering to?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: The code has two `lea` instructions, one of which sets `eax` for use as a base register, the other of which sets `ecx` to an address used to compare with `edx`. But they are stepped in synchronization, just offset from each other, so the same effect could be obtained by adjusting `edx` by an offset prior to the loop and comparing with `eax` instead of `ecx`, making the second `lea` in the loop unnecessary. My guess is there is no difference in execution time, as the loop is bound by the `inc` instructions, and the `lea` fit in the loop with no time cost.

Comment: Yes, maybe there is no difference in execution time in most cases. But the loop is 1 instruction larger than required. So if there is pressure for number of instructions in loop or pressure for ALU resources, then additional `LEA` instruction can give 1 cycle penalty for loop in some corner cases.

Comment: Generally, if you want optimal code, MSVC is usually not the best choice of compiler.  As Agner Fog mentions (https://www.agner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=88&sid=e47a6286d6550687e1e26b82e422bba1), Visual Studio can use clang-cl.  Maybe there's some way of writing the source differently that would trick MSVC into not pessimizing the asm with LEAs that can't run on as many execution ports on all CPUs.  But I wouldn't hold out too much hope.  BTW, GCC and clang are rarely perfect either, including sometimes wasting an instruction on a loop counter with `lea` and then `mov`.

Comment: I also saw that counter version can produce more slow `load [base + index * 4]` on clang. The idea with pointer version is to simplify things for compiler. Also if there is register number pressure, then we don't need to change limitation variable in memory (load + compare), while counter version can require 3 operations (load + decrement + store) in that case.